# How to go back and forth in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In xcode and in eclipse there is a version where we can go back and forth to our last cursor location.

For example, say I am editing one function. Then I go to the definition of that function. Then I want to go back to the first function.

Say I am editing A() that call B(). In A(), I go to the definition of B() and I want to go back to editing A() again.

How do I do so?

Comment: This is clearly not a programming question.

Comment: Sure. No programmer will ask this.

Comment: This is clearly a valuable answer :-)

Comment: To achieve this with the mouse: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/87fb8c65-d1db-49e9-a068-d62a222a4ae7

Comment: Sparky and co seem to have closed this question because it wasn't a programming question yet their own rules say questions about software tools are acceptable: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "if your question generally covers...software tools commonly used by programmers...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!".

Comment: Why can't this be unclosed?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use Control-minus (Ctrl- "-"). See [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip9.asp)

If it doesn't work, it's probably because you use a different key binding. Go to `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboad->"View.NavigateBackwards"` and add your key (Don't forget to Apply !)

Comment: @JimThio and anyone else for that matter: It works for me, however, I cannot use the minus key on my numeric keypad I have to use the one above my letters.

Comment: +1 for every body and this is the best answer :D

Comment: Ctrl-Shift+"-" goes forward for me.

Comment: If it still doesn't work after adding your shortcut, look at the 'shortcut currently used by', unlike in many games, you can have multiple commands using the same shortcut, even in the same 'context' (text editor, global, other editors, ...). Clearing the shortcut for other commands that apply for text editor helped me.

Comment: As an alternative, I always use Ctrl-Tab. This will cycle to the last seen code file - in this manner I can easily swap back & forth between dependent files, while still holding my cursor position.

Answer (score 18):

Use the "Ctrl"-"Shift"-"-" to move forward after you have used "Ctrl"-"-" to move back.

see [Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/01/navigate-backward-and-navigate-forward/)

Comment: doesn't work. Should I activate something first

Comment: Make sure that you have visual studio default key binding set up. If you have resharper or any other power tools installed you might have overridden the default key bindings. You can verify this from Tools -> Options in visual studio

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) plugin for Visual Studio, which (among other things) allows me to use the Back and Forward buttons on the mouse.

For a keyboard shortcut, I use Alt-Left Arrow for back, and Alt-Right Arrow for forward.  I don't know if that's through Visual Studio or Visual Assist X.

Comment: I believe Alt - Left/Right arrow keys are for visual assist. Doesnt work on my VS 2010

Comment: There are Forward/Back Navigation buttons on the toolbar.  Prior to using VA X, several of my coworker set up a key mapping to those buttons, and then bound the forward/back mouse buttons to those keys.  Not an ideal solution, but it worked for them.  You can also get a trial version of VA X.  When the trial expires, I think the navigation enhancements still work.  I'd recommend the full version of VA X, it makes C++ in VS a lot nicer.